# How to pass data from 2nd viewcontroller to tableviewcontroller using delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have 2 `viewcontroller`s - one is a `tableview` and the other is a normal `viewcontroller`. I want pass data from the second `viewcontroller` to a `tableview` controller by using delegates. I have created a delegate and `delegatemethod` in `viewcontroller` and implemented `delegatemethod` in the `tableview` controller. The problem is that I am getting data to the array but `tableview` is not reloading. Why?

Can anyone help with this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
    #import "TableViewController.h"

        @interface TableViewController ()<name>{

            NSMutableArray *data;
        }

        @end

        @implementation TableViewController

        - (void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            data = [NSMutableArray array];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }

        - (IBAction)callingSecondView:(id)sender {

            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            ViewController *var = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc"];
            var.delegate = self;
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:var animated:YES];
        }
        -(void)getdata:(NSString *)name{

            [data addObject:name];
            [self.tableView reloadData];

        }
        #pragma mark - Table view data source

        - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

            return 1;
        }

        - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

            return [data count];
        }
        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"  forIndexPath:indexPath];

            if (cell != nil) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

            }
            cell.textLabel.text = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            return cell;
        }
```

And I am creating delegate a object and protocol in `ViewController.h`

```
        #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

        @protocol name <NSObject>

        -(void)getdata : (NSString *)name;

        @end


        @interface ViewController : UIViewController
        @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txt;
        - (IBAction)done:(id)sender;

        @property(nonatomic,retain) id<name> delegate;
```

`ViewController.m`

```
        #import "ViewController.h"

        @interface ViewController ()

        @end

        @implementation ViewController
        @synthesize delegate;
        - (void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];

        }
        - (IBAction)done:(id)sender {

            [delegate getdata:self.txt.text];
            [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        }
        @end
```

Comment: i think you have to reload tableview from View controller itself...From where your are sending data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first VC don't reloadData because it's not the visible VC. Try reloadData when the VC willAppear.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```